# How to installing leiden library using R languanges and fix this error?

Tags: python, r, anaconda, rstudio, leiden

ERROR :

library(leiden)

create conda environment (yes/no)?yes

yes

Unable to set up conda environment r-reticulate

run in terminal:

conda init

conda create -n r-reticulate

conda environment r-reticulate installed

python modules igraph and leidenalg installed

```
# Install required packages
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("kharchenkolab/leidenAlg")
library(leiden)

# Read CSV files
data1 <- read.csv("file1.csv")
data2 <- read.csv("file2.csv")
data3 <- read.csv("file3.csv")

# Combine data into one data frame
data <- rbind(data1, data2, data3)

# Perform clustering using Leiden algorithm
result <- leiden(data)

# Plot the results
plot(result, data)
```